# Configuring smart switch. Message “This site can’t provide a secure connection”. There is a mismatch between my browser and this devices protocol

Tags: http, https

I may be able to update the firmware on this switch if I can login to it.

This is a Netonix WS-12-250-DC switch. These are great switches for remote locations where all I have is DC power. I have configured a few of these and their GUI interface is impressive.

I can SSH to the switch. But I don't seem to be able to figure out the CLI  commands.

Does anyone know how to disable the SSL version checking in any browser. The only thing on the network is 1 PC and the Netonix switch.

I have tried different browsers (chrome, edge, firefox) and Setting the switch to factory defaults.
I still get the message
This site can’t provide a secure connection
192.168.1.20 uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
and
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

I am not concerned with security with this device. I will be once it is in service. But, I need to get to it to configure it.
I think this device is only supporting http on port 80. I could configure https if I could log in. The browser automatically redirects my http to https (presumably port 443 or 8443)

Comment: Not a software development question. Ask on [su]